# Element top margin doesn't seem to change

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have some text, and beneath it a button. No matter what I change the top margin to, the button still sticks to the bottom of the text.

I am trying to leave a small gap between the text and the button.

Here is a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24bk2t78/

```css
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300);


.homethree a    { text-decoration: none; }
sup  { font-size: 36px; font-weight: 100; line-height: 55px; }

.button
{
 margin-top:30%!important;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #0C5;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 position:relative;
 padding: 20px 0;
 width: 220px;
 height:30px;
 background: #0D6;
 border: 1px solid #0D6;
 color: #FFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button:hover, .button:active 
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C5;
  border-color: #0C5;
  background: #FFF;
}

.button span 
{
 
  padding-right: 0;
  
  transition: padding-right 0.5s;
}

.button span:after 
{
  content: ' ';  
  
  right: -18px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
 

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;

  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.button:hover span, .button:active span 
{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.button:hover span:after, .button:active span:after 
{
  transition: opacity 0.5s, top 0.5s, right 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: #0C5;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center homethree">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="service-heading">A Range of Classes</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">WE TEACH CHILDRENS CLASSES, FAMILY GROUPS & ADULTS.</p>
     <a href="#" class="button"><span>page 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Passionate Instructors</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">ALL OUR CLASSES ARE TAUGHT BY PASSIONATE, MOTIVATIONAL & INSPIRING INSTRUCTORS.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button"><span>page 2</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Friendly Team</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">NEW MEMBERS ARE ALWAYS WELCOME. TWO FREE LESSONS FOR ALL.</p>
  <a href="#" class="button"><span>page 3</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<a>` tags are `inline` elements. Changing them to an `inline-block` or `block` style element will make your margins properly apply.

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

More info: [The Difference Between “Block” and “Inline”](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/)

On a sidenote, why not use `<button>` tags instead of `<a>`? They would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to be working now! Will mark as correct as soon as I can

Comment: I should probably update it to a '<button>' tag. It was just a simple link to start with, and developed it from there, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this demo
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24bk2t78/4/)

```
.button{
    float:left;
    margin-top:0;
     }
.col-md-4
 {
    float:left;
    width:100%
 }
```